# Chrome Extension - Unable to import playwright

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, chromium, playwright

I am using plasmo for developing a chrome extension to automate webpage interaction. I want to use playwright for all the DOM related interactions. But I am unable to import chromium. I think it is because of some packages that cannot be used in V8 chrome engine but are available for normal Node js execution runtime.

```
const minimumMajorNodeVersion = 14;
const currentNodeVersion = process.versions.node;
const semver = currentNodeVersion.split("."); <- this is the line which throws error saying currentNodeVersion is undefined.
```

Can you please help me how to import playwright into a chrome extension with or without plasmo.

Comment: `playwright` runs the browser, it doesn't run *in* the browser [by design](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4738).